# I'm currently working with micropython with esp32. Can i work with espsecure.py in command line without the help of esp idf to secure esp32?

Tags: esp32

Does esp idf support micropython? As my code is build using micropython, I can't work with espidf. How can I secure esp32 without the help of espidf?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of ESP-IDF supporting MicroPython - MicroPython is built on top of ESP-IDF. It's a matter of whether ESP-IDF functions have been exposed in MicroPython.

Some ESP-IDF functionality is made visible in MicroPython through modules that allow hardware-independent functionality - for instance, the `network` module allows you to call network-related functions in the same way on any processor with networking.

Some ESP-IDF functionality is made visible in MicroPython via the [esp](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/esp.html#module-esp) and [esp32](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/esp32.html#module-esp32) modules, which are specific to those processors.

If no one has written an MicroPython module exposing the ESP-IDF functionality you need, you can write one yourself. This is documented in the [Extending MicroPython in C](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/extendingmicropython.html) page in the MicroPython documentation.

However not all ESP-IDF functions will work well with MicroPython. For instance, you're likely to get into trouble if you start using FreeRTOS tasks (a part of ESP-IDF) with MicroPython. And MicroPython may simply not link in all ESP-IDF functions that you need, so you may have to build a custom MicroPython image that includes the ESP-IDF functions you require.

As for how you secure the ESP32 - that is an incredibly broad and vague question. If you post a specific question about security and MicroPython someone may be able to help you with it. But the MicroPython environment is not designed to be "secure" in the sense of preventing tampering or reverse-engineering.

Comment: I want to enable secure boot and flash encryption

Comment: That's done by setting e-fuses, not in the application code. Secure boot will sign the MicroPython firmware but will not help with the code MicroPython loads. Flash encryption will by default only protect the firmware and partition table; you'll need a custom partition scheme which marks the filesystem that stores the Python files as encrypted. That may not be sufficient... as I said, MicroPython is not designed for this.